# Newbie Flex question: getting a reference to an object from within a .as file

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am modifying some Flex code written by someone else.  There is an mx:text control that I want to change the 'text' property of.  I know how to do this within the .mxml file in which the control is defined, however I don't know how to do this from within a separate .as ActionScript file.  I recall in Flash there is some way to fully qualify the reference by prepending the stage or something like that, but I don't know how to do this in Flex.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this as file connected with mxml (inherits from it)? If not, you need to pass the reference to mxml class (or Text control) to class in as file.

Comment: The .as file simply has a bunch of functions, it does not define a class.... I see now that the Flex manuals says that all I need to do is give my mxml control an 'id', and then I can reference that control from any .as file by using the id.  So why would this not simply just work?

Comment: I should have stated initially that the error I am getting is in Eclipse, and I now think after a lot of Google-ing that this is an Eclipse error, not a Flex error.  Sorry about that.

Comment: id works when your code is in mxml file, in Script block. Look, mxml file defines class, not instance. How you can reference unknown instance from unrelated file? In short, give some code examples (essential part) and we'll solve that.